# Google adwords SOAP Request - TargetingIdeaService and TrafficEstimatorService

Tags: soap, google-api, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

Kindly anyone share the request xml for the below services

https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/o/v201506/TargetingIdeaService?wsdl

https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/o/v201506/TrafficEstimatorService?wsdl

If possible, please share with some working test account developer token..

Comment: welcome to Stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you know a better way to ask my question, kindly edit and update..